# Odd C++ strict-aliasing warning

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

The following is a whittled-down version of my code for a `unique_pointer`-like class implementation that still exhibits the problem:

```
#include <tr1/type_traits>

template<typename T>
class rv : public T {
  rv();
  ~rv();
  rv( rv const& );
  rv& operator=( rv const& );
};

template<typename T,typename D,bool = std::tr1::is_empty<D>::value>
struct pjl_ptr_storage {
};

template<typename T,typename D>
struct pjl_ptr_storage<T,D,true> : private D {
  T *ptr_;

  pjl_ptr_storage( T *p ) : ptr_( p ) { }
  pjl_ptr_storage( T *p, D &d ) : D( d ), ptr_( p ) { }

  D& deleter() { return *this; }
};

template<typename T>
struct default_delete {
};

template<typename T,class D = default_delete<T> >
class pjl_ptr {
public:
  explicit pjl_ptr( T *p = 0 ) : storage_( p ) { }
  pjl_ptr( rv<pjl_ptr> &p ) : storage_( p.release(), p.storage_.deleter() ) { }

  T* release() {
    T *temp = storage_.ptr_;
    storage_.ptr_ = 0; // dereferencing pointer ‘<anonymous>’ breaks strict-aliasing rules
    return temp;
  }

  operator rv<pjl_ptr>&() {
    return *static_cast<rv<pjl_ptr>*>( this );
  }

private:
  pjl_ptr_storage<T,D> storage_;

  pjl_ptr( pjl_ptr& ); // forbid
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef pjl_ptr<int> int_ptr;

int_ptr f() {
  return int_ptr( 0 ); // this line triggers the warning above
}

int main() {
}
```

Using g++ 4.4.3 compiled with `-O2 -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing`, I get: `dereferencing pointer <anonymous> breaks strict-aliasing rules` on the line tagged above.  This happens to be on an Ubuntu 64-bit system.  If I compile the same code using g++ 4.6.1 on Mac OS X Lion, I get no warning.

I understand strict-aliasing rules in general (or so I think), but I don't understand why it's complaining about the line in question.

Is g++ 4.4.3 wrong?  Assuming it's correct, how can I tweak the code to get rid of the warning, i.e., not break strict-aliasing rules?

Comment: @Autopulated: I did -- no effect.

Comment: Code compiles fine for me as well.

Comment: 1. I never said the code didn't compile. I said g++ issued a warning (not an error). 2. What g++ version and OS are you using? 3. Did you give the exact same command-line options to g++?

Comment: Can you reduce this to a minimal test-case?

Comment: The above *is* a minimal test-case (as I stated in my first sentence).

Comment: On my system, 4.4.6 issues the warning, 4.5.2, 4.6.2, and 4.7-current do not

Comment: solved the problem? i guess u didn't compiled with c++11, did you? If so, maybe u should use nullptr instead 0, as far ptr isn't just pseudo pointer. I don't get that good through your code... but also looks for me as an upcast, could that be the problem by casting an objects element?

Comment: @Zaibis: your comment is unintelligible.

Comment: Hm in how far? I dont get what you mean with unintelligible. For mear it looks clear. But the problem vcould als be my english. Could you specify what yo dont udnerstand?

Answer (score 0):

`gcc` doesn't like that you cast `this` (You can try to replace `this` with, e.g, `0` and see whether the warning will disappear; I think it will). So you have two pointers to the same memory but with different types (`pjl_ptr` and `rv<pjl_ptr>`). gcc warns you that (e.g. due to some optimizations) changes made through `rv<pjl_ptr>` pointer (e.g. assignment to`storage_.ptr_`) may become not visible through `pjl_ptr` pointer.

Personally I don't see how it can lead to a problem in your case, but it looks like gcc is correct.

PS. I'm not a standard guru, so I don't know what exactly standard think about it :)

Comment: Changing `this` to `0` does in fact remove the warning (but you'd think g++ would have complained about the line of the cast).  But given that later g++ versions don't give the warning, it's not clear that g++ 4.4.3 is right.  Regardless, casting through void* still doesn't suppress the warning.

Comment: g++ complains about assignment because of the next words from c++ standard: `If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through an lvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined: <list of allowed lvalues here>`. So UB is assigning, not casting.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why later versions of g++ don't report the warning.  Your answer also doesn't say how to tweak the code to prevent the warning (legitimize the code).

Comment: Why g++4.6 doesn't warn you? Tons of possibilities: they changed something in inliner; they broke optimizer; they decided that the warning is useless because the code will work even it is not allowed by standard; so on, so on, so on...
How to legitimize? Don't dereference the invalid pointer.

Comment: "_changes made through rv<pjl_ptr> pointer (e.g. assignment tostorage_.ptr_) may become not visible through pjl_ptr pointer._" But why? (Don't bother. The code is nonsensical anyway.)

Comment: During optimization compiler can put `storage_.ptr_` into a register. When it is changed, compiler will not reread it into the register. Actually, it will reread, but the standard allows not to reread if the strict aliasing rule is breaked.

Comment: @Yuras: how can the code be altered so as not to generate the warning?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to do.

```
template<typename T>
class rv : public T {
// private: by default
  rv();
  ~rv();
  rv( rv const& );
  rv& operator=( rv const& );
};
```

No accessible ctor and no friend. You cannot possibly have an instance of that class.

Comment: Yes you can by casting, which is all it's used for to generate a distinct type.